# Camera calibration parameters not appropriate for SVO package

Tags: calibration, ros-hydro, camera, ethzasl-ptam, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been trying to use the [SVO package](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo) using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro, but I ran into trouble with the calibration file. In the [SVO calibration guidelines](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Camera-Calibration) says that the [camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration) package can be used to obtain a calibration file that works with SVO, but the format of the calibration file expected by the SVO looks like this:

> cam_model: Pinhole cam_width: 752

> cam_height: 480 cam_fx: 414.536145

> cam_fy: 414.284429 cam_cx: 348.804988

> cam_cy: 240.076451 cam_d0: -0.283076

> cam_d1: 0.066674 cam_d2: 0.000896

> cam_d3: 0.000778

And the one obtained with the camera_calibration, after convertir to yaml using the [camera_calibration_parsers](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration_parsers) looks like this:

> image_width: 1024 image_height: 768
> camera_name: narrow_stereo
> camera_matrix:   rows: 3   cols: 3
> data: [1114.338842, 0, 488.044082, 0,
> 1483.616573, 384.580052, 0, 0, 1] distortion_model: plumb_bob
> distortion_coefficients:   rows: 1
> cols: 5   data: [0.089323, -0.327338,
> -0.003856, -0.002099, 0] rectification_matrix:   rows: 3
> cols: 3   data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
> 0, 1] projection_matrix:   rows: 3
> cols: 4   data: [1117.866699, 0,
> 485.532623, 0, 0, 1492.567993, 382.458084, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

I do not see how to make SVO work with the calibration file I'm getting and I have also not found a way to convert said file to the format that works.

I found another forum question where a person with my same problem got to the conclusion that the camera_calibration file didn't work with SVO and that the ATAN format file from [ethzasl_ptam](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam) had to be used instead. But when I try to implement the ptam package I get a missing header error that I haven't been able to solve either (it's [this error](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/issues/39), but the solutions found in that thread haven't worked for me neither in Hydro nor in Groovy). Which is why I need to make the camera_calibration file work.

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197954/camera-calibration-parameters-not-appropriate-for-svo-package/) by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2014-11-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see in [OpenCV Camera Calibration](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) your file will end up being:

```
cam_model: Pinhole
cam_width: 1024
cam_height: 768
cam_fx: 1114.338842
cam_fy: 1483.616573
cam_cx: 488.044082
cam_cy: 384.580052
cam_d0: 0.089323
cam_d1: -0.327338
cam_d2: -0.003856
cam_d3: -0.002099
```

The values of fx, fy, cx, and cy are located in the 3x3 camera_matrix and the d0, d1, d2, and d3 in the 1x5 distortion_coefficients array.

Modify your camera parameters file manually and see if this works.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) with karma: 182 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2014-11-26**:
Thank you very much! It never occurred to me that I already had all the information I needed for the file, I should have read the documentation better.

Thank you!